# How to reverse simple bilingual dictionary

Tags: xml, dictionary, xslt, reverse

I want to reverse a simple bilingual dictionary for our local history club. This means that the translations should become entries, whereas entry words change into translations. In the example I use English verbs hoping that the purpose will be more clear.

`trefwc` is the entry word cluster, `trefw` is the entry word, `vertacl` is the translation cluster, `voorbcl` is the example cluster, `voorb` is the example.

```
<items>

<items>

<item>
<trefwcl>
<trefw>Twiefele</trefw>
<label>ww</label>
</trefwcl>
<vertacl>
<verta>doubt</verta>
</vertacl>
</item>

<item>
<trefwcl>
<trefw>Rikraoje</trefw>
<label>ww</label>
</trefwcl>
<vertacl>
<verta no="1">be in dubio</verta>
<verta no="2">doubt</verta>
</vertacl>
</item>

<item>
<trefwcl>
<trefw>Afkükele</trefw>
<label>ww</label>
</trefwcl>
<vertacl>
<verta no="1">fall off</verta>
<verta no="2">get off</verta>
</vertacl>
<voorbcl>
<voorb>nice example phrase which will be translation </voorb>
<verta reverseword="doubt">translation which will be example at entry doubt</verta>
</voorbcl>
</item>

</items>
```

My present output is this:

```
<items>
<item>
   <trefwcl>
      <trefw>doubt</trefw>
   </trefwcl>
   <trefwcl>
      <trefw>Twiefele</trefw>
      <label>ww</label>
   </trefwcl>
</item>

<item>
   <trefwcl>
      <trefw>be in dubio</trefw>
   </trefwcl>
   <trefwcl>
      <trefw>Rikraoje</trefw>
      <label>ww</label>
   </trefwcl>
</item>
<item>
   <trefwcl>
      <trefw>fall off</trefw>
   </trefwcl>
   <trefwcl>
      <trefw>Afkükele</trefw>
      <label>ww</label>
   </trefwcl>
</item>
<item>
   <trefwcl>
      <trefw>get off</trefw>
   </trefwcl>
   <trefwcl>
      <trefw>Afkükele</trefw>
      <label>ww</label>
   </trefwcl>
</item>

</items>
```

The example cluster does not even appear.

My desired output would be like this:

```
<items>
<item>
   <trefwcl>
      <trefw>doubt</trefw>
   </trefwcl>
   <vertacl>
      <verta>Twiefele</verta>
      <label>ww</label>
   </vertacl>
<voorbcl>
    <voorb>translation which will be example at entry doubt</voorb>
    <verta>nice example phrase which will be translation </verta>
</voorbcl>
</item>

<item>
   <trefwcl>
      <trefw>be in dubio</trefw>
   </trefwcl>
   <vertacl>
      <verta>Rikraoje</verta>
      <label>ww</label>
   </vertacl>
</item>

<item>
   <trefwcl>
      <trefw>fall off</trefw>
   </trefwcl>
   <vertacl>
      <verta>Afkükele</verta>
      <label>ww</label>
   </vertacl>
</item>

<item>
   <trefwcl>
      <trefw>get off</trefw>
   </trefwcl>
   <vertacl>
      <verta>Afkükele</verta>
      <label>ww</label>
   </vertacl>
</item>

</items>
```

This is the xsl file I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="items">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="vertacl/verta|voorbcl/verta/@reverseword">
    <item>
      <trefwcl><trefw><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></trefw></trefwcl>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/*[not(self::vertacl/verta|self::voorbcl/voorb)]" group-by="local-name()">

<!-- I do not even know in this setting where to add the vertacl and verta. -->

         <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*" />
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </item>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::*)]">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried other variants, and somehow managed to get the example put to the entry doubt, but it was still not what I need.

Comment: Why have the examples moved from `Afkükele` in the original to `Twiefele` in the expected output?

Comment: This is merely an fictitious example, sometimes an example cannot be connected to a noun or verb extant in the example itself because the word has been conjugated and changed. Therefore in general an explicit reverseentry is needed.

Comment: Is this question not answered?

Answer (score 1):

***--- edited in view of comments ---***

AFAICT, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="eg" match="voorbcl" use="verta/@reverseword" />

<xsl:template match="/items">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="vertacl/verta">
            <item>
                <trefwcl>
                    <trefw>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    </trefw>
                </trefwcl>
                <vertacl>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <verta>
                            <xsl:if test="last() > 1">
                                <xsl:attribute name="no" select="position()"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:value-of select="trefwcl/trefw"/>
                        </verta>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="trefwcl/label"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </vertacl>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('eg', current-grouping-key())"/>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given your example (after removing the extra `<items>` start-tag), this will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item>
      <trefwcl>
         <trefw>doubt</trefw>
      </trefwcl>
      <vertacl>
         <verta no="1">Twiefele</verta>
         <label>ww</label>
         <verta no="2">Rikraoje</verta>
         <label>ww</label>
      </vertacl>
      <voorbcl>
         <voorb>nice example phrase which will be translation </voorb>
         <verta reverseword="doubt">translation which will be example at entry doubt</verta>
      </voorbcl>
   </item>
   <item>
      <trefwcl>
         <trefw>be in dubio</trefw>
      </trefwcl>
      <vertacl>
         <verta>Rikraoje</verta>
         <label>ww</label>
      </vertacl>
   </item>
   <item>
      <trefwcl>
         <trefw>fall off</trefw>
      </trefwcl>
      <vertacl>
         <verta>Afkükele</verta>
         <label>ww</label>
      </vertacl>
   </item>
   <item>
      <trefwcl>
         <trefw>get off</trefw>
      </trefwcl>
      <vertacl>
         <verta>Afkükele</verta>
         <label>ww</label>
      </vertacl>
   </item>
</items>
```

which is still not *exactly* what you show as the expected output  - but I believe my version is more logical. In any case, it should be a good starting point for you to adapt as required.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your suggestion. I try to find solutions of problems presented by other people, which I then adapt. For me there is no 'simple', but it is fun, of course. The logic of the placement of the example is that @reverseword indicates at which (future) entry in the reversed dictionary I want the example to appear. So I need this example to appear at 'doubt'. I also want only one entry 'doubt'. I am sorry if the examples are not clear enough.

Comment: If there should be only one entry for `doubt`, should it not list BOTH `Twiefele` and `Rikraoje`?

Comment: Yes, thanks, you are right!

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hopefully this will put you on the right track.

Comment: I tried it, and it works! Thank you for your help! There is one thing left: in the example voorbcl, voorb and verta need to interchange. What is verta in the original, changes into voorb in the reversed version, and what is voorb changes into verta.

Comment: Well, then instead of `<xsl:copy-of select="key('eg', current-grouping-key())"/>` use `xsl:for-each` and make the change there.